# Please automatically make my comment topmost

Tags: feature-request, comments, moderator-tools

...when I leave my comment as part of a moderator action.

I've struck this a few times: I have processed a flag on a post, and left a comment at the same time. As a moderator this particular comment is important - it can contain helpful hints or guidance for new people, it can contain a simple reason for a closure or deletion. But due to the number of comments already on the post my comment is not visible unless the user clicks the `show x more comments` link and then scrolls down.

Two ways of achieving this functionality could be:

- any comments left while on the *Moderator Tools - flags* page should automatically be ordered topmost
- if I leave a comment on a post that has pending flags then give me an option to force the comment to be topmost (in this case don't do it automatically)

Note that with these comments I'm leaving information or instructions that are not covered by the post notice feature. I don't expect this feature to get much use on a busy site like Stack Overflow, but I consider it to be quite useful on a quieter site where you have more time to help or guide new users (that guidance can be crucial for the long term sustainability of quieter sites). While the OP will get a notification for the comment so is likely (but not guaranteed) to see it, other members are unlikely to see it if it is buried down the list of comments.

Answer (score 14):

I don't think having your new comment show up *first* will do what you want -- people who have been engaging in the comment thread (there must be a lot of comments if yours is disappearing) jump down to the bottom to pick up where they left off, and an out-of-order comment will confuse some readers.

What we really need, I think, is for the comment to be always visible.  There should be a way for a moderator to leave a *notice*, a comment that begins with something like "**Moderator notice:**" and is visible even without comment votes.  There should be no more than one such notice on a post.  (Familiarity breeds contempt, and mods suffer enough contempt on some sites already.)

Ideally this would be chosen by the moderator, not done automatically based on where the mod was when he left the comment.  There's already enough stuff that happens automatically and isn't always intuitive; let's not add to the cognitive load.  I'm not sure what the best affordance for this would be -- maybe another icon (a pin?) that shows up next to *your own* comments, or maybe a moderator-only flag type (you would need to be able to flag your own comments, which currently you can't).

Currently, on one of my sites where this sort of thing is needed fairly often, we write the bold notice by hand and ask another moderator to upvote the comment.  But we're spread out around the world and there isn't always another moderator around, so while this works it doesn't always work well.  We haven't started asking random denizens of the Teacher's Lounge to provide the needed votes, but maybe that's a workaround if the situation is particularly grim.

All that said, are you deleting enough comments?

Comment: Hi Monica, good suggestion about the pin instead of the result based on where the action happened. Although I'm still unsure about whether *still visible* is sufficient - if it was topmost it is first and therefore not throwing out the order of subsequent comments. I am cleaning up enough comments, but I'm hesitant to remove those that add context - I try not to be too OCD about the comments :)

Comment: @slugster How about the same order, but always visible, and a different background color? Something with a reasonable level of contrast with the specific site's default background (I wouldn't recommend an obnoxious amount of contrast, or red, just a clear and conspicuous distinction).